# What is the proper way to pass exceptions in asynchronous methods in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, asynchronous

I'm not sure what the proper method would be to pass exceptions in asynchronous methods in GWT. I have a dataservice which connects to a database, queries for information and then returns it to the client. But I don't understand fundamentally what to do when a checked exception occurs and how to handle it.

Currently I have something like this

```
public int addAssembler(int assemblerID, String name, boolean active) {
        Connection con = connect();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            String query = "INSERT INTO assemblers (name, hidden) VALUES ('" + name + "'," + active + ")";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            System.out.println("addAssembler " + ps.toString());
            ps.executeUpdate(query);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(rs, ps, con);
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

and it is called here

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Ioma.dataservice.addAssembler(0, name.getText(), !isActive.getValue(), new AsyncCallback<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        Window.alert("Failed to add assembler! Please check error log" + caught.toString());
                    }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Integer result) {
                    Window.alert("Assembler " + name.getText() + " added");
                }
            });
```

I realize that the SQLException is caught in my try/catch but I'd like the method to fail and I'd like to pass it back onFailure, how do I do this? I tried

```
public int addAssembler(parameters) throws SQLException {}
```

but it gives me a source code not found error for SQLException. I'm also not even sure if this the correct way to do any of this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [this section](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html#exceptions) of the documentation.

You can't throw `SQLException`, because the client doesn't know what that is. What you can do, is define your own Exception type (in your client or shared package):

```
public class DatabaseException extends Exception implements IsSerializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7935074533073743071L;

    public DatabaseException()
    {
        super();
    }

    public DatabaseException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

    public DatabaseException(Exception e)
    {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

Then declare it in your service method:

```
public interface MyService extends RemoteService {
    int addAssembler(int assemblerID, String name, boolean active) throws DatabaseException;
}
```

Then you can throw it on the server side:

```
public int addAssembler(int assemblerID, String name, boolean active) throws DatabaseException {
    Connection con = connect();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO assemblers (name, hidden) VALUES ('" + name + "'," + active + ")";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        System.out.println("addAssembler " + ps.toString());
        ps.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DatabaseException(e); // <----- THIS IS IMPORTANT
    } finally {
        close(rs, ps, con);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

On the client, the `onFailure(Throwable caught)` method will then be called and you can do the following:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
{
    if(caught instanceof DatabaseException)
        Window.alert(caught.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Comment: BTW: You don't have to do that for all `Exception`s, just the ones that aren't [emulated already](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).

Comment: And make sure to log it on the server. And think *really* hard about sending the full stack trace and message of a SQL exception to the client - if there was a sql injection or connection string issue happening, do you *really* want to send the 'hey, here is how you break me!' message to the browser?